# Can not Clear field (clear()) not working

Tags: python, selenium

I can not clear the field ('text1) 'to type a new text ('text2')

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('serviceName').click()
self.driver.find_element_by_id('serviceName').clear()
self.driver.find_element_by_id('serviceName').send_keys('text2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear does not always work for me either. You could try a few creative solutions, such as Keys.Backspace in a loop.

```
def clear_element(element):
    length = len(element.get_attribute('value'))
    element.send_keys(length * Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

You could also try a CTRL + A / Backspace combo:

```
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
element.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

Lastly, you can try Javascript:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '';", element)
```

The final possibility could be the WebElement you are trying to clear does not accept key strokes for some reason. Usually, Selenium with throw an `InvalidElementState` or `ElementNotInteractable` exception if this is the case, but not always. If none of these solutions work, you could proceed by posting the HTML of the page you are using, and this will help.

Comment: I use `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '';", element)` and it's working super fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christine you are the best, always present when i need help ;)